# What is rational number equivalent of 1.83838383... using Taylor Series (do not use fraction method)?

Tags: calculus

What is rational number equivalent of 1.83838383 using Taylor Series (do not use fraction method)?

Comment: What exactly is the "fraction method"? What have you tried?

Comment: It's $\frac{182}{99}$, independent of any method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1+83\left(\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{10000}+\cdots\right)$$
$$=1+\frac{83}{100}\left(1+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100^2}+\cdots\right)$$
$$=1+\frac{83}{100}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{100}}$$
$$=1+\frac{83}{100}\frac{100}{99}$$
$$=1+\frac{83}{99}$$
$$=\frac{182}{99}$$

Is that what you mean by Taylor series?

Comment: Thank You this really helps . :) My bad i didnt copy the question properly.